# port forwarding - cannot get access to IP

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

```
india827:~# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:a4:14:08  
          inet addr:85.25.152.115  Bcast:85.25.152.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::219:99ff:fea4:1408/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2752215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1061558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1274090951 (1.1 GiB)  TX bytes:506433382 (482.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:18 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:a4:14:08  
          inet addr:85.25.248.216  Bcast:85.25.248.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1023499 (999.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1023499 (999.5 KiB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ae:ba:ce:d7:7d:bd  
          inet addr:10.0.1.254  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::acba:ceff:fed7:7dbd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:1211 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
india827:/pyvbox# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3135 packets, 455K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10   660 ACCEPT     all  --  tap0   any     10.0.1.0/24          anywhere            ctstate NEW 
   32  1536 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             10.0.1.0/24         ctstate NEW 
   23   920 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2887 packets, 1135K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

    india827:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
85.25.248.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 eth0
85.25.152.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 tap0
0.0.0.0         85.25.248.193   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         85.25.152.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Telnet from server (localhost):

```
india827:/pyvbox# telnet 85.25.248.216 3389 
Trying 85.25.248.216...
Connected to 85.25.248.216.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Telnet from remote PC:

```
H301:~# telnet 85.25.248.216 3389
Trying 85.25.248.216...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Traceroute (from remote host):

```
H301:~# tcptraceroute 85.25.248.216 3389
traceroute to 85.25.248.216 (85.25.248.216), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  213.155.20.253 (213.155.20.253)  0.538 ms  0.640 ms  0.731 ms
 2  80.93.126.57.ett.ua (80.93.126.57)  0.176 ms  0.236 ms  0.238 ms
 3  decix.ett.com.ua (80.81.192.113)  30.795 ms  30.810 ms  30.812 ms
 4  tge-5-1-0-353a.cr2.fra.routeserver.net (80.81.192.21)  31.031 ms  31.017 ms  31.090 ms
 5  * * *
 6  217.118.16.163 (217.118.16.163)  36.565 ms  36.459 ms  36.410 ms
 7  static-ip-85-25-248-216.inaddr.intergenia.de (85.25.248.216)  34.580 ms  33.987 ms  34.163 ms
 8  static-ip-85-25-248-216.inaddr.intergenia.de (85.25.248.216)  38.088 ms  34.822 ms  34.665 ms
```

iptables rules

```
india827:~# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 14134 packets, 2307K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   48  3032 ACCEPT     all  --  tap0   *       10.0.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           ctstate NEW 
  107  5764 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.1.0/24         ctstate NEW 
  953  398K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9820 packets, 16M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination     


india827:~#  iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 14181 packets, 2115K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  865 47089 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            85.25.248.216       to:10.0.1.1 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 13713 packets, 2021K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2113 packets, 122K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2984 packets, 169K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   20  1115 SNAT       all  --  *      eth0    10.0.1.1             0.0.0.0/0           to:85.25.248.216
```

What is incorrect in my configuration?

Comment: Could we get the output of `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn` on your remote PC?  I note that your eth0:1 address is in a different subnet to your eth0 address, so my first thought is routing.

Comment: Added the output to the 1st post. The network settings (eth0 and eth0:1) were provided by hoster.

Comment: Maybe the port blocked by a firewall? Run `tcptraceroute 85.25.248.216 3389` to see if the packet is blocked somewhere along the way. Run `iptables -nvL` to see the firewall rules on the server. Also run `netstat -tn | grep 3389` to see what interfaces the server is listening on.

Comment: Attached to the 1st post. The netstat will show nothing because it's running on virtual machine on virtual interface (tap0), and all ports from external interfaces are fowarded to the tap0.

Comment: If you read carefully, I actually asked for the output of `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn` **running on your remote PC**, but the traceroute output has made that irrelevant.  Could you try `tcpdump -n -n -i eth0 port 3389` on the server whilst doing the telnet on the remote PC and see if we can at least confirm that the request is getting to your server?

Comment: `14:06:57.796679 IP 178.86.2.16.35395 > 85.25.248.216.3389: Flags [S], seq 2025029930, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 302186306 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:06:57.797124 IP 85.25.248.216.3389 > 178.86.2.16.35395: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2025029931, win 0, length 0`

Comment: There is no firewall rules on my remote pc. For example, I can telnet 3.ds-2.ax-host.ru 3389 from it without any problems.

Comment: I see the syn coming in, the syn-ack leaving, but the final ack never coming back.  Are you able to get to any other ports on india827 from H301, like sshd?

Comment: All the ports from the eth0:1 are forwarded to 10.0.1.1: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 85.25.248.216 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1

Comment: The ports on eth0 are available from any IP.

Comment: Hang on, are you saying that the eth0:1 address is DNATted, and moreover to something down the other end of some kind of (Open)VPN tunnel?  If so, I think your network geometry is a tiny bit more complex than you've led us to believe.

Comment: india827 is running VirtualBox and has main interface eth0. Virtual Machines are with WinServer 2003 & there is virtual interface for host=only network with VMs. eth0:1 is alias for one of VMs and have its own external IP address, and I'm trying to forward all packets from it to VM's IP on tap0.

Comment: It worked perfectly before I cleared iptables rules and I think I forgot to add some rule...

Comment: If its portforwarding run

  iptables -t nat -nvL and past the stats here.

Comment: Added to the 1st post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies, the problem is solved. I just cleaned up all the rules & applied the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 85.25.248.216 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -d 10.0.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```